# What are some methods to choose a $n$ for Quasi Monte Carlo Integrations?

Tags: monte-carlo, quasi-monte-carlo

When studying "simple" Monte Carlo integration methods, such as Hit or Miss, Crude , Importance Sampling, etc. A common problem for first time learners is to choose a number $n$ of points that they will use for their function without knowing the value of the integral beforehand. Usually, this can be solved by making some simulations for certain $n$'s and calculating their standard deviation and standard error or building the confidence interval, checking if they are suitable for your problem. This works because since the numbers are random, even for an equal $n$ you will obtain different approximations for your integral, making it possible to analyze if they vary too much or not.

But I have a hard time imagining how this could work for those methods when utilizing quasi random sequences as samples. I believe that my problem comes from how can I compute any relevant estimator for a $n$ since all the simulations using it will hold the same approximation? How can I know/show that increasing my $n$ is actually helping it to get more accurate approximation if I don't have a variance for the $n$?

One idea that I had was maybe try to compute the relative error between different approximations, and if they are small enough, maybe that could indicate a lesser variability. (Something like the relative error between an approximation of $n$ and $10n$)

Any articles or book chapters on the matter could also be greatly appreciated!